# Como hacer para que un componente de boostrap se quede fijo

Tags: css

estoy haciendo una pagina con boostrap, y mi pregunta es:

Como hago para que si tengo un elemento de boostrap, y quiero que se quede en una posicion fija independientemente de que si hay un scroll o no.

ejemplo:

```
<head>
    <title> Take a note </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lateral.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>

<!--  barra de arriba -->
<div class="fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light barra">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Takeanote</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
   </div> 

<div>
        <p style="position:relative;padding-right:5px;">imagen</p>
    </div>


   <div>

    <p style="position:relative;padding-right:0px;">usuario</p>
    </div>


</nav>
</div>
<!--  panel lateral -->

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Mis Apuntes</a>
  <a href="#">Favoritos</a>


 </br>
 <a href="#">Apuntes</a>
 <a href="#">Documentos</a>
 <a href="#">Ejercicios</a>
 <a href="#">Practicas</a>

</div>

<!--  campo normal, el contenido vamos  -->
<div style="padding-left: 10%" class="sticky-top">


<div style="margin-top: 55px;position:sticky;">
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb " >
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">ULL</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Informatica</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Sistemas Operativos</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">tipo de archivo</th>
      <th scope="col">usuario</th>
      <th scope="col">valoracion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Tengo dos barras  de navegacion horizontales y necesito que estas esten estaticas y las entradas si que se hagan scroll

CSS:

```
body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    .barra{
      padding-top: 0%;
     position: fixed;
    }

    /*   panel lateral  */
    .sidenav {

      height: 100%;
      width: 10%;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #1111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

    /*     las letras dentro del panel      */
    .sidenav a {
      padding-left:10%;
      padding-top:5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;

    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    .main {

      width:match-parent;

    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
```

Comment: Ya leíste la documentación de Bootstrap? En CSS existe la propiedad `position`. Puedes revisar [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/) y [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: si, el tema es que en mi caso tengo dos barras de navegacion, y aunque con la primera, lo que tu me aconsejas funciona, con la segunda no, ya que se solapan.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade el código que te está generando ese problema específico para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: ok, dame un momento

Comment: Qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando?

Comment: version 4.0.0, lo tengo descargado en local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hace falta añadir la clase `.fixed-top` al segundo `nav` horizontal para que se aplique lo que deseas.

También era necesario que le añadieras `margin-top: 55px;` para que no quedara justo debajo del primer `nav`. Ya lo tenías y es correcto.

Espero sea lo que necesitas.

```css
body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    .barra{
      padding-top: 0%;
     position: fixed;
    }

    /*   panel lateral  */
    .sidenav {

      height: 100%;
      width: 10%;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #1111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

    /*     las letras dentro del panel      */
    .sidenav a {
      padding-left:10%;
      padding-top:5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;

    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    .main {

      width:match-parent;

    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<!--  barra de arriba -->
<div class="fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light barra">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Takeanote</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </div>
   </div> 

<div>
        <p style="position:relative;padding-right:5px;">imagen</p>
    </div>


   <div>

    <p style="position:relative;padding-right:0px;">usuario</p>
    </div>


</nav>
</div>
<!--  panel lateral -->

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Mis Apuntes</a>
  <a href="#">Favoritos</a>


 </br>
 <a href="#">Apuntes</a>
 <a href="#">Documentos</a>
 <a href="#">Ejercicios</a>
 <a href="#">Practicas</a>

</div>

<!--  campo normal, el contenido vamos  -->
<div style="padding-left: 10%" class="sticky-top">


<div class=fixed-top style="margin-top: 55px;">
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb " >
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">ULL</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Informatica</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Sistemas Operativos</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">tipo de archivo</th>
      <th scope="col">usuario</th>
      <th scope="col">valoracion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Tema1.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>1138</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>papadomcmenu</td>
      <td>996</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bash1</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>santikiller32</td>
      <td>660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tema2.pdf</td>
      <td>apunte</td>
      <td>k1k4ss0</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bash2</td>
      <td>practica</td>
      <td>Tostadorav2</td>
      <td>540</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias (no era exactamente lo que buscaba) pero me sirve igualmente , muchas gracias !!!!